# Adding reject reason when choosing to reject suggested edit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, rejection-reasons

Sometimes rejecting a suggested edit is not obvious and having reason will help both the people who need to cast the second vote and the people viewing the suggested edit history later, as well as the person suggesting the edit. Better help him/her learn than just rejecting without saying why.

So, having the ability to add some short optional comment while rejecting will be great idea in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If the suggested edit is worth to accept, but it has some small defects, the Approver can improve it. But if the suggested edit is completely worthless, direct reject it without any reason.

Adding reject reason will enhance the approving suggest edit's complexity too much. Let us think about the processing logic:

1.The user who approving suggest edit reject a revision with input a reject reason.

2.The editor read the reject reason, then reedit it, and submit again.

3.Approver approve it again.

So reciprocating...

Why not the Approver improve the first suggest edit revision by himself/herself?

Comment: I'm not suggesting to notify anyone of the comment - this will indeed be too much. The editor can see the comment only after the edit was rejected, and if he suggest new edit, most likely other people will have to approve/reject it. But yes, better he knows what to improve rather than having to guess. Regarding improving, many people won't have the time and will anyway but of course this is the ideal way.

Comment: Maybe you're right. But I still feel it is not necessary.

Comment: That's OK, don't expect everyone to agree. :)

Comment: re why not improve - in the cases I wanted to comment the comment was totally wrong and the original better - so a reason would be the only way to tell the editor