# Can we be shown the rejected edit reason on overview?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

When going through the suggested edits, sometimes I am curious as to why another reviewer has chosen to reject an edit. It would be great if we could see the reject reason that the other person selected, similar to what we see on the 'Why should this question be closed' dialog.

Can we place a marker or flag similar to this:

[image]

on the `Why are you rejecting this edit` dialog?

[image]

I looked to see if this was requested before but all I found was [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94808/adding-reject-reason-when-choosing-to-reject-suggested-edit) which is asking for a reason for the original editor.  I think it would be helpful to see why other reviewers are rejecting an edit.

Can this be added?

Comment: I believe a similar idea has been presented before, but I think imitating the way close votes work is an excellent solution to this, even if the blue box will only ever contain a `1`.

Comment: @animuson I think it would be helpful at this to assist reviewers to see why others think it is a bad edit. I think it would overall improve the way edits are reviewed.

Comment: I'm a SO newbie so maybe I don't understand the feature request workflow but is there a reason why there is no answer ?

Comment: +1 I think this is especially important for copied content/plagiarism. If I'm the first reviewer and I happen to notice that the content looks plagiarized, there's no way to communicate this to further reviewers. Even if I vote to reject, it seems unlikely either of the next two reviewers would also notice the same thing. They would likely say "Looks good, Approved", as they had no way to know it was copied.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature has been implemented now. Whenever the rejection dialog is opened, if the suggestion is rejected by other user(s), it will show us the reason for the rejection same as closing dialog like this:

[image]

Comment: But was it implemented at the time this question was asked..?

Comment: @Daedalus - Obviously no. Otherwise why was this feature request was added and got 15+ upvotes?

Comment: Then why the past tense as if it had already been implemented..  I mean, that's what it comes across to me like.  In my opinion the wording of this answer should be something akin to 'this has been implemented', or something similar.  'Already' kind of implies.. well, hopefully you can realize what I'm referring to.

Comment: @Daedalus - Oh yes you are correct. Updated the answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: This does not help much as to spot plagarism you want to see that before you choose to keep

Comment: Funny thing is, I noticed that this was completed a while ago but I actually forgot that I asked this on meta. :)